# Pug (express view engine) nesting with conditionals

Tags: express, nested, conditional-statements, pug, rows

i'm using pug as my viewengine for express (node js), but im having trouble with some conditionals. I use a grid framework for newsletter designs which works similar to bootstraps grid, meaning i have rows and columns. I need two items per row, which requires to define a new row every two items. I tried it this way:

```
each elem,index in elements
  - var even = index % 2;
  if(even)
    .row
      .column
  else
      .column
```

This doenst work as intended, because the else-column is not nested insinde the row column. I could only find the pugjs.org documentation which is a bit poor on this end, so does anyone have experience with this or a link to more documentation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you add your expected html output ?

Answer (score 2):

Pug ignores extra indentation, so what you've written is correctly interpreted as:

```
each elem,index in elements
  - var even = index % 2;
  if(even)
    .row
      .column
  else
    .column
```

Note that the last `.column` is truly a sibling of `.row`.

Instead, try this—

```
each element, index in elements
  if !(index % 2)
    .row
      .column
      if (index + 1 < elements.length)
        .column
```

When index is even (remember it starts at 0) do the following:

- Render a row element with one column
- If this isn't the last element, add a second column

When index is odd, do nothing (because we already added the second column).

Note that even though it looks like the second column will be rendered as a child of the first column, the contents of an `if` statement render at the indentation level of the `if` statement—so they'll be siblings.

Comment: This is neat! pug can walk the array once to build the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Process `elements` into groups of two.

```
- 
    const groupedElements = elements.reduce(function(acc, curr, index) {
        let isEven = (index + 1) % 2;
        if (isEven) {
            acc.push([curr]);
        } 
        else {
            acc[acc.length-1].push(curr);
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);

for group in groupedElements
    .row
    for item in group
        .col
```